# Isolating contents between multiple matches with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings that look like the following:
"1y 250 2y 32% 3y otherjibberish".

My ultimate goal is to split it into the following:
"1y 250"
"2y 32%"
"3y otherjibberish"

The main 'separator' between these splits are the "\d+y" patterns. Using Regex (C# 4.0), I can use the Matches function to match a number followed by a 'y', but I don't know how to get everything that follows that match but precedes the next match.

Is there a way to do that?

Hopefully that makes sense.... Much appreciated 
- kcross

Comment: will there ever be more or less than 2 spaces between each `\dy` delimiter (barring first/last ones)?

Comment: yes, that can be variable (part of it is user input, so you can't guarantee two spaces...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "MatchCollection" to split the string according to the occurrences.
The example below does almost what you want. The blank character at right of each string is not removed.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Q11438740ConApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceStr = "1y 250 2y 32% 3y otherjibberish";
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"\d+y");
            string[] splitedArray = SplitByRegex(sourceStr, rx);

            for (int i = 0; i < splitedArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("'{0}'", splitedArray[i]));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string[] SplitByRegex(string input, Regex rx)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(input);
            String[] outArray = new string[matches.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                int length = 0;
                if (i == matches.Count - 1)
                {
                    length = input.Length - (matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    length = matches[i + 1].Index - (matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length);
                }

                outArray[i] = matches[i].Value + input.Substring(matches[i].Index + matches[i].Length, length);
            }

            return outArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'1y 250 '
'2y 32% '
'3y otherjibberish'
```

"Solution" 7z file: [Q11438740ConApp.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11438740ConApp.7z)

Answer (score 0):

This was actually quite easy... Just used the Regex.Split() method.

Comment: Note: You'll lose the numeric value if you do split (you'll get `{ " 250 ", " 32% ", " otherjibberish"}`. You can infer the order, but unordered elements will be trouble

Comment: What pattern do you use to do the split? When I do it, the number remains.

Comment: My console app looks like this `Regex regex = new Regex( @"\d+y" );
   string input = "1y 250 2y 32% 3y otherjibberish";

   foreach( string s in regex.Split( input ) ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "Item: " + s );
   }`